# VPN connection button doesn't show Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to configure my vpn and find these commands in a turorial. However, none of them work:

I've installed the following packages:

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-openvpn-vpnc
network-manager-openvpn-pptp
openvpn
```

I have tried to start a daemon and to start it with systemctl.

Checking with ifconfig, no virbr0 has emerged and there is no graphical option for VPN Connection.

I've done through dozens of theads and tutorials and none seem to have the problems persisting like this. I did the same thing to another computer yesterday, and after some tweaking it worked. I've even tried graphic install via Software Center.

What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. Turns out I need this package too:

```
Network-manager-gnome
```

And then launch via

nm-connection-editor